# How was Akatsuki members able to replace their bodies?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto Shippuuden Episode 16,I came across the scene where Akatsuki members were controlled with in another bodies.What kind of jutsu is that?[image: Yurra_wearing_akatsuki clothes]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are looking for this.
It is called as the Shapeshifting technique used by pain.
According to the Wiki:-

> This technique allows Pain to allocate a portion of an individual's
>   chakra and transfers it into a living human sacrifice, allowing the
>   original to fight via an elaborate "copy". The appearance of the
>   person on whom the Shapeshifting Technique is performed is completely
>   identical to the original person. The technique will imitate any
>   weapons, tools or kekkei genkai held by the original person, allowing
>   the copy to fight with them. The power of the copy is in proportion to
>   the volume of allocated chakra, which is decided by Pain.

If you want some more info then you can check [Kazekage Rescue Arc](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha) on this page and some more about the [jutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shapeshifting_Technique).